# Why are some methods defined with an uppercase first letter?

Tags: ios, swift

I was looking at the Apple documentations and some of the methods such as [Sec​Item​Copy​Matching(*:​*:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1398306-secitemcopymatching) are defined with an uppercase first letter. Isn't the convention for methods a lowercase first letter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions (not methods) are originally `C` APIs. They have different naming conventions than Apple's Obj-C APIs.

With Obj-C (or pure Swift) APIs, the uppercase names are reserved for classes. With C APIs there are no classes but the prefix identifies a pseudo-object (`SecItem`).

It should be noted that some C APIs are now imported into Swift as objects, for example `CGContext` (based on [Swift Evolution 0044](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md)).

Comment: I am only familiar with object oriented languages and have trouble understanding: where do the functions that have not been imported as objects (unlike `CGContext`) fit. For example, regular, class methods in Swift are available through an object or a type respectively. Are the C function you are referring to just available globally anywhere (without an object or a type) by calling their signature?

Comment: @A.Jam Yes, in C they are available everywhere. However, Swift gives them a module to live in depending on the name of the original framework. For example, the qualitifed name for `SecItemCopyMatching` is `Security.SecItemCopyMatching`. Note that C has no concept of modules therefore the name collisions have to be solved using prefixes (in Obj-C the same applies actually). That's why we have `CG` prefix for `CoreGraphics` etc.